# android getView loading wrong picture after scrolling fast

Tags: android, adapter

I have one big big problem, i just have some "ArrayList items" and i have problem with getView method.
I am trying to load background image (if needed) to the row depending on the status of the TRIP (custom class).

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

layout = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.custom_layout);
String status = items.get(position).getStatus();
                if (status.equals("Cancelled"))
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic_status_cancelled);
        if (status.equals("Closed"))
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic_status);
```

When first opened the ListView all is good and then after scrolling fast down and up ...  pictures are messed up (wrong pictures loaded for status). 
Please help me and explain me what causes the problem.
Thanks

EDIT: I found the solution ... 
It was because i didn't make if statements for all CASES and because it reuses the view.. cannot consider to the default values you put in xml.

Comment: its due to listview recycling views

Comment: and how to solve it? what is the solution to this?

Comment: use a view holder http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html. start by reading the docs

Comment: post your full code of `getview` with the updated code

Comment: edited with solution. thanks anyway man